# limit is also bounded if sequence is bounded and converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

assume $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(a_n\right)=\:L$,and for every n, $a_n\in \left[c,d\right]$. 
It is true to say that $L\in \left[c,d\right]$?
I can't think of opposite example for this so i think its true. help?

Comment: $[c,d]$ is closed and contains all its limit points!

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi yes but how can we prove this?

Comment: $L$ is an accumulation point. What happens when $L\notin [c,d]$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $L\notin [c,d]$, you can find an epsilon neighborhood of $L$(the red part in the figure below), which contains all but finitely many points of the sequence $\{a_n\}$ **(why?)** and $(L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)\cap [c,d]=\emptyset$

What contradiction do you get?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Assume the limit lies outside of $[c,d]$. Say the limit is $L$ and assume without loss of generality that $L>d$. Let $\varepsilon$ be such that $\varepsilon < L-d$. Therefore: $$\exists n_0\in \mathbb N \mid \forall n\geq n_0 \ |L-a_n|<\varepsilon <L-d$$ $$\Rightarrow L-a_n<L-d\Rightarrow a_n > d$$

Which is a contradiction with the hypothesis of every $a_n$ being in $[c,d]$. The argument is analogous if $L<c$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose $L \not\in [c, d]$ :

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(a_n\right)=\:L \iff \forall \epsilon>0, \exists n_0>0 \text{ s.t. } \forall n>n_0, |a_n-L| < \epsilon. $$

Then take $\epsilon = \frac{min(|L-d|, |L-c|)}{2} $ for example, and conclude.